# Dart multiple upper bounds

Tags: dart

I need to implement a solution using generics that implements 3 interfaces, but as far as I can tell, generics in dart only supports 1 upper bound?

I have a model that looks like this:

```
abstract class Category implements Built<Category, CategoryBuilder>, Identifiable, Mapable {
   ...
}
```

The contents of the 3 interfaces is not really relevant, and what I'm trying to do, is construct a class that can process this in generic form.

What I want is something like this:

```
abstract class BaseDB<T extends Built<T, R> & Identifiable & Mapable, R extends Builder<T, R>> {
   process(T entity) {
      print(entity.id); // From Identifiable
      entity.toMap(); // From Mapable
      // ... etc
   }
}
```

I know this is possible in both Typescript and Java, but I'm fairly new at Dart. Anyone know?

Comment: Funny, that's EXACTLY my problem, I am also trying to abstract a DB with an `Identifiable` interface for `id` and using built_value.

Comment: It got tricky and unreadable real fast (like i alluded to in my response below). Ended up just casting to `dynamic` in a few places. Cheaty, but ultimately easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid it, but after reading your experience that's what I am going to do.

Comment: (Actually I cast it to `Identifiable`, but yeah, same thing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible in Dart. You can only put one bound on a type variable.

The bound of a Dart type variable is used to check which operations you can do on an object of the type parameter type. Example:

```dart
String something<T extends num>(T value) {
  return value.abs().toString();
}
```

You are allowed to call `abs()` on `value` because we know that all instances of `value` are numbers, and `num` has an `abs` method.

If you can write `<T extends Foo & Bar>`, then there is no simple type in the Dart type system that can describe objects of type `T`. Dart does not have *intersection types* (the intersection type `Foo & Bar` would be a supertype of all types that are subtypes of both `Foo` and `Bar`, and a subtype of both `Foo` and `Bar`).
If `Foo` declares `Baz method()`, `Bar` declares `Qux method()`, and `value` has type `T`, what is the type of `value.method()`? 
(It would either be disallowed, or the type would be `Baz & Qux`). This shows that allowing `&` in type variable bounds leaks intersection types into the remaining type system, and since Dart does not have intersection types, it also does not have multiple bounds on type variables.

When you declare a class, `FooBar`, implementing both `Foo` and `Bar`, you have the same issue: You need to figure out what `method` returns. However, the language *requires* you to *write* that solution into your class, to find some valid return type for `FooBar.method`, because otherwise the `FooBar` class declaration is not valid. It requires a user to find a solution to "find a subclass of both `Baz` and `Qux`".

Comment: Good answer. I know you can probably chain the class hierarchy to contain the required methods, but it feels overly complicated and verbose. Currently I'm accessing `.id` and `.toMap()` via a simple cast using `(entity as dynamic).id`, but it doesn't really feel optimal.